# Inverse of the sum of a symmetric and a skew symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, inverse

Consider the following matrices $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $B\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, with $A=-A^\top$, $B=B^\top\leq0$.

From several analytical calculations it turns out that

$$
(A+B)^{-1}=C+D,
$$

with $C=-C^\top, D=D^\top\leq0$.

1. Can anyone provide a proof for this to hold for any n?
2. Is there any analytical formulation for the matrices C and D?

EDIT: If this is of some relevance or help in proof, I might be interested also in the case that B is strictly negative.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: _Every_ square matrix $U$ can be written _uniquely_ as the sum of a symmetric matrix and a skew-symmetric matrix. Without further information on how $C$ and $D$ depend on $A$ and $B$, the assertion $(A + B)^{-1} = C + D$ is therefore contentless (i.e., trivial). Are you simply asking for this decomposition? (Separately, if $A$ and $B$ are both zero, say, then $A + B$ is not invertible. Is $B$ negative-definite rather than negative semi-definite...?)

Comment: It is further asked that D is negative semidefinite. Has this general validity? Regarding semi definiteness or definiteness of B I'm interested in both cases.